# Importar csv sem duplicar registros

Tags: mysql, csv

Tenho uma planilha com 32000 registros, e preciso jogar para uma tabela no banco de dados. O problema é que nessa planilha não tenho o ID dos registros e não posso deixar duplicar quando fizer a importação.
Preciso fazer com que quando eu fizer a importação, ele verifique pelo campo "loja" (que é o nome/razão social da loja), caso já exista, ele deve atualizar o registro com os dados da planilha, e caso não exista, ele criará um novo registro na tabela.

Comment: Você sabe SQL certo?

Comment: Particularmente, eu iria inserir TODOS os registros em uma tabela de apoio. Após toda essa importação concluída para o banco, faria a inserção na tabela final somente dos registros únicos, ignorando os registros duplicados. Isso me garante não ter que refazer caso algo de errado.

Comment: Acredito eu que o foco seria o desempenho, já que há diversas maneiras de fazer. Eu faria a inserção geral na tabela destino, e depois um select distinct ou group by, e os registros que somarem mais que 1, excluir.

Comment: Essa planilha é excel?

Answer (score 0):

Crie a tabela que você vai importar como chave primaria no campo "loja".
E no script de importação adicione o REPLACE.
Caso ele encontre o mesmo registro ele irá atualizar, exemplo:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.csv' REPLACE INTO table[...]
```